# How to get detailed shared url data via Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Anyone know the Facebook API endpoint to get a list of pages (not only the number of sharing but include information of each share) which shared a specific webpage like the crowdtangle extension does as below screenshot.

[crowdtangle extension screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouSK9.png)

I have tried the url endpoint but return only the total number of share:

```
?id=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&fields=engagement
```

Update: My final goal is to get which business page shared my specific webpage and the engagement of these posts.

Thank you!!

Comment: i guess you mean "user profiles", not pages, right? what´s the use case for this, why would you need to know which users shared something?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the social data of a webpage, here is the updated screenshot:
https://i.imgur.com/LraXqIh.png

Comment: and i mean "list of pages who shared the website" - i assume you are not really talkking about pages, but user profiles? there is a big difference. anyway, the question about the use case is actually the important one for a reliable answer :)

Comment: Nope, I am taking Facebook business pages. My final goal is to get which business page shared my specific webpage and the engagement of these post.

Comment: ok, i highly doubt that you can get that information. and "engagement" (if you mean the engagement of the shared post, not the initial one) is something you would normally only get if you manage a page.

Comment: I don’t think what you want is available via any public API. Services like this might benefit from the number of users they have - if you have enough big pages that gave you admin access, so that you can their individual data, you can assemble that to a “larger picture”. And some scraping might probably be involved, too.

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes, I think it might not a public endpoint since crowdtangle is a Facebook company and these data might exclusive to them. Anyway, I just check in case I have missed anything in the document.